# Insert/add array to an array

Tags: c#

I'm having problem with array or JSON in C#. The problem is, I want to insert arrays inside an existing object.

```
class Bands
{
    public string BandName { get; set; }
    public string Songtitle { get; set; }
}

public JsonResult Band()
{
    var items = new Bands()
    {
        BandName = "amber",
        Songtitle = //how to add array here;
    };
    return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Output:

```
[
    { "bandname": "maroon", "songtitle": {} },
    { "bandname": "amber pacific", "songtitle": {} }
]
```

How do I insert the song title?

Comment: Could you be more specific? It's a little vague... Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do you need a string array?

Comment: Change `songtitle` to be a collection. `public List<string> Songtitles { get; set; }`

Comment: Can you show the code that generates that output and the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the attribute `Songtitle` and convert it into a `List` of `string`. Then, when you are creating a new `Band` add many songs as you want to the list.

Code below:

```
private class Bands
{
    public string BandName { get; set; }
    public List<string> Songtitles { get; set; }
}

public JsonResult Band()
{
    var items = new Bands()
    {
        BandName = "amber",
        Songtitles = new List<string> { "song 1", "song 2" }
    };
    return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```